# Python error when indexing dataframes or when trying to use pandas functions like df.info() or df.head()

Tags: python, callable

I'm getting an error when I run the python code below. I'm trying to generate a range of dates to perform some time series forecasting.

```
langenddate = currentdate + pd.DateOffset(months = 4)
prestartdate = startdate - pd.DateOffset(months = 4)
dates= pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(prestartdate,langenddate,freq='M'))
dates
```

However, when I try to perform anything on the resulting dataframe, I get some errors shown below. I get the same error when I do

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'
```

When I try to get the df info I get the following error

```
dates.info()

ValueError: Only callable can be used as callback
```

I was running this block of code and it was working just fine up until yesterday. Not sure if I've done anything wrong. I was trying to change some library versions. Not sure if that's the issue??

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: what is the value of `currentdate` and `startdate` before you start?

Comment: ahh sorry. they are 
`currentdate = date.today().replace(day = 1)
startdate = currentdate + pd.DateOffset(months = -11)`

Comment: When I ran this I didn't get any errors, please provide your full code along with the full traceback.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I think it's a package version? I was changing some package versions. It's resolved after I just restart my spyder kernel.